# Copy paste string to terminal leave a dangling empty area appearance

Tags: terminal, bash

If you see the bell on the title, it means when I deleting string it was reaching $ sign and give a bell warns. But the strange thing is my cursor is not completely clear the string, it is still leaving my URL left over there. I already checked PS1 on my bash profile and it looks like this

```
export PS1='\e[1;32m\W \t \e[1;31m\u \e[1;32m$ \e[0m'
```

But when I resize the window of the terminal, suddenly it turns back normal.

[image: copy paste]

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose the non-printable characters properly in `\[...\]` block. This ensures that correct number of characters are counted while generating the prompt.

I had the same problem and here's the PS1 that gave no issues so far :

```bsh
\[\e[30;47m\]$(parse_git_branch)\W\[\e[30;47m\]$\[\e[0m\]
```

That is my understanding of what I read on SO:

> You should add `\[` before any starting ANSI code and add `\]` after
>   any ending ones.   Example:   in regular usage:  `\033[32mThis is in
>   green\033[0m`   for PS0/1/2/4:     `\[\033[32m\]This is in
>   green\[\033[m\]`
>
> `\[` is for start of a sequence of **non-printable** characters   `\]`
>   is for end of a sequence of **non-printable** characters
>
> Tip: for memorize it you can first add `\[\]` and then put your ANSI
>   code between them:
>     - `\[start-ANSI-code\]`
>     - `\[end-ANSI-code\]`

https://stackoverflow.com/q/5947742/28938235#28938235

https://stackoverflow.com/q/17432993/

https://stackoverflow.com/q/20697195/20698168#20698168